# Should a service marked as UNHEALTHY if it's too busy?

Tags: load-balancing, microservices, health-monitoring

The Health Check is just like a simple *ping-pong* test, if the service has no response, then it's unhealthy. If something is unhealthy, there should be an alarm for it.

But, should I mark the service as *unhealthy* if it's too busy but still responsive (*maybe it's just a short time overloading*)?

Most of the Health Check [doesn't have a `BUSY` state](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/health-checking.md) (*only a `SERVING` and 
 a `NOT_SERVING` state*)

```
enum ServingStatus {
    UNKNOWN = 0;
    SERVING = 1;
    NOT_SERVING = 2;
}
```

It makes no point to connect to the busying service. But since it's still working properly, it's still count as a healthy service right?

Or the load balancer should still be able to connect to it, but the service should return a `TOO_BUSY` status to refuse the incoming requests (*then why not just mark it as **unhealthy***)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reasons for not marking it unhealthy:

1. If your service manager restarts unhealthy services, then it might do more damage.
2. If you need to wake your team up at 3am because of an unhealthy service, but not because of a busy service, you're wasting your team's energy.
3. If your service is unhealthy because you're infrastructure lacks the proper adjective, then add the adjective. 
   And finally and most importantly:
4. The real question is, why are you trying to prevent load from your service? Are you afraid that requests will fail because the server is too busy responding? Maybe its time to scale. How would your autoscaler ever know that your service needs to scaling if whenever its busy, loads start to magically relieve themselves. Your autoscaler needs the service to be busy so that it can scale. If you aren't using an autoscaler, then why do you care if its "BUSY" or "UNHEALTHY"?